# Stopping image from scrolling paraScrolling

Tags: javascript, css

edit-  I actually had my image originally position:relative. I have fixed that in my code. I would like the image to scroll left until it has disappeared from the window. I would like it to stop moving, or even reset. I can do that part. I used the developer window in chrome to check, and the position:right of the image in question moves on well past 1700px, which I tried to stop with my if block in paraScrollRight

I'm trying to get an image to stop moving, so that I can get another image to move while the user scrolls down the page. For some reason, my if logic doesn't stop scrolling at all.

```js
var yPos, image;

function paraScrollDown(){
 
  yPos = window.pageYOffset;
  image = document.getElementById("image");
  image.style.top = (yPos * 1.0) + "px";
}

function paraScrollRight(){
 
  yPos = window.pageYOffset;
  image = document.getElementById("image");

  if(image.style.right <= 1,374 + "px") {
    image.style.right = (yPos * 2.7) + "px";
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll",paraScrollRight);
```

```html
<img id="image" style="position:relative" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/ee/94/32/ee94322ba44eebc686d2e8381a84259c.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/92rse23e/

I only handled the `paraScrollDown` method since that's what I understood what you needed to be taken care of. An important thing you needed to add was to make the image `position: absolute;` in CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually had my image originally position:relative. I have fixed that in my code. I would like the image to scroll left until it has disappeared from the window. I would like it to stop moving, or even reset. I used the developer window in chrome to check, and the position:right of the image in question moves on well past 1700px.